# If $f(x)=\max(1-\cos{x},2\sin{x})$ for all $x$ in $(0,\pi)$, Then $f'(x)$ is undefined at $x=x_0$ where $2\sin x_0+\cos x_0=1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

Okay,I am new to Calculus. I tried to find Maxima of $1-\cos{x}$ and $2\sin{x}$  in the interval $(0,\pi)$ and it turns out that they have the same local Maxima ($=2$). I don't know how to proceed. Here is the problem

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

To find $max (1-\cos (x),\sin (x)) $
note that

$$1-\cos (x)=2\sin^2 (\frac x2) $$

and
$$\sin (x)=2\sin (\frac x2)\cos (\frac x2) $$

If $x\in (0,\frac \pi 2) $ then
$\sin (\frac x2)<\cos (\frac x2) $ and 
$$f (x)=\sin (x ) $$
if $x\in (\frac \pi 2,\pi) $ then
$$f (x)=1-\cos (x) $$

from here

$$f'(\frac \pi 2^+)=1$$
$$f'(\frac \pi 2^-)=0$$

Comment: I can compute the maximas . They are equal. So which one to take as f(x)? Moreover, it ask whether f'(x) is not defined at any x=x_0 where 2snx_0+cosx_0=1

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury is that what you want.

Comment: That would be 2sinx which is equal to 4sin x/2 cos x/2, which changes the thing I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is an $x$ for which the derivative is undefined but I think it's not $x=\pi/2$.

Plot the two individual functions in the same axes. The point in which the two cross each other is the point where the derivative of $f$ is undefined.

Comment: Actually it had three options :a) π/12, b)5π/12, c)x=x_0 such that 2sinx_0+cosx_0=1 d)π/2. A book claims π/2, just merely.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury It's the last one. Try to think about why. Cheers

Comment: Any hints if you may? I have been able to sketch the graph. I am a beginner you see.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury use this link for plots http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=b794a03744a03800313ca0f2e291294